# select seven cells down macros

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macros to select seven cells down from the selected cell, merge them and rotate text. The ploblem with my macros is that it does not work with ANY cells. Can anyone help

```
Sub Merge7()
'
' Merge7 Macro
'

'
    Range("A10:A17").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 90
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 20
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Range("A18").Select
End Sub
```

I wanted to use it with any cells not just A10:A17

Comment: Have you tried delete the lines `Range("A10:A17").Select` and `Range("A18").Select` and select the required range on the sheet and then call the macro?

Comment: This would beat its purpose. I want the cells to be selected automatically. I neet to run it like 500 times, selecting one by one is too slow

Answer (score 0):

### Apply to Active Cell

**Usage**

```vb
Sub Merge7()
    MergeBelowCell 7
End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub MergeBelowCell(Optional ByVal CellsBelow As Long = 1)
    
    With ActiveCell.Resize(CellsBelow + 1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 20
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
        .Orientation = 90
        .Offset(1).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. I just needed help to change "A10:A17" to a comand the will select seven more cells below the already selected cell, run the rest of the code, then chane the "A18" to select the next cell below.